# Postgres 10 shutting down on installation in Ubuntu 14

Tags: postgresql, errors, error-log

On trying to install postgres on Ubuntu 14 I am seeing postgres is shutting down. I am seeing the below errors in logs

```
[19043] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
[19043] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
[19044] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-12-16 02:41:39 PST
[19043] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
[19051] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
[19043] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
[19043] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
[19043] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 19050) exited with exit code 1
[19045] LOG:  shutting down
[19043] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Can some one let me know what could be going wrong? Why is postgres shutting down after the installation ?

Comment: What's the question specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432, listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432", database system is ready to accept connections

  > Just your server starting up.
- database system was shut down at 2017-12-16 02:41:39 PST

  > You always get this message at bootup, it's produced by the ["expected state"](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/af9f8b7ca343eefa33b693d7919d8f945aeee3e7/src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c#L6291) of the write-ahead log manager.
- incomplete startup packet

  > Nothing happened here.. [a client buzzed in and then left.](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Incomplete-startup-packet-help-needed-td5199030.html), produced by a backend.
- received fast shutdown request, aborting any active  transactions, database system is shut down, worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 19050) exited with exit code 1

  > This is just the postmaster shutting down

Comment: Thanks Evan. Can you please explain a bit more about the last bullet logical replication launcher exited. What is impacted if postmaster is shut down? How can I get more info why postmaster is shutting down?

Comment: Postmaster shuts down as part of systemd. Exit code 1 from the worker, just shows that it should not be restarted back up. It got the signal to shut down, and it did. Exit code 0 would be session termination (as compared to top-down shut down request from init.)

Comment: It doesn't explain how to fix it. I need postgres to run, not be shut down